# EMACS Fatal Error 6: Aborted

Tags: gtk3

I'm running Elementary OS Hera and I downloaded EMACS because Mozart Programming System requires it.
When I try to open EMACS a windows pops up and then it vanishes. Y tried opening it from the Terminal and this is what I get:

```
$ emacs
X protocol error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) on protocol request 139
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.
Fatal error 6: Aborted
Backtrace:
emacs[0x50a4de]
emacs[0x4f0ad9]
emacs[0x50a583]
emacs[0x4c0920]
emacs[0x4c4c69]
emacs[0x4c4ceb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XError+0x11a)[0x7f05f24cd8fa]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3d82b)[0x7f05f24ca82b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3d8d5)[0x7f05f24ca8d5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XEventsQueued+0x55)[0x7f05f24cb205]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XPending+0x5d)[0x7f05f24bcd3d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x6809e)[0x7f05f3ce809e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_prepare+0x1c8)[0x7f05f2c33b28]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x4c4fb)[0x7f05f2c344fb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_pending+0x27)[0x7f05f2c34687]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_events_pending+0xd)[0x7f05f41a5a9d]
emacs[0x4c1327]
emacs[0x4f7a01]
emacs[0x4f8095]
emacs[0x5b2740]
emacs[0x5b3d48]
emacs[0x5b40d4]
emacs[0x49299a]
emacs[0x499ce5]
emacs[0x5231b3]
emacs[0x563b59]
emacs[0x598413]
emacs[0x565ead]
emacs[0x5639fb]
emacs[0x5669d9]
emacs[0x588cd1]
emacs[0x563b59]
emacs[0x598413]
emacs[0x565ead]
emacs[0x5639fb]
emacs[0x563cfa]
emacs[0x56cf0c]
emacs[0x56d36f]
emacs[0x563b92]
emacs[0x598413]
emacs[0x565ead]
...
Aborted
```

The [link](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715) below is a Gnome Bug that seems to be 17 years old. It is closed. 
There is no a `etc/PROBLEMS` file or directory.

I used to run EMACS on Ubuntu 19.10 and I didn't have any problem.

Please let me know if you need any other information or if this is more a GTK error than EMACS.

Comment: Though the bug is affecting Emacs, this doesn't really seem like an Emacs question. If no  one provides an answer here soon you might want to delete it here and post it somewhere else (e.g. some site about GNOME).

Comment: You could try compiling Emacs from source with a different X toolkit.  GTK is only the default.  You could try `./configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid` and/or `./configure --with-x-toolkit=motif`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered on https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-to-get-gnu-emacs-work-on-elementary-os already.

Comment: The discussion mentioned by wasamasa seems relevant.  E.g. it explains that the real problem is the *first* line of output (not in the link to the old Gtk bug that's still not fixed).  I don't know if it's truly a bug in ElementaryOS or Emacs, but it's clearly as bug somewhere.  You should include the version of Emacs you're using.  And if it's the latest release, you should `M-x report-emacs-bug`.